# If statement conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to include an IF statement result in the same cell as the result of a formula in Microsoft Excel. Below is what I mean

Cell 1 = the answer to a formula e.g =SUM(I19)-Sum(K19/100*I19)

I want to include an IF statement in the same cell to say that if the value of Cell 1 < 0, then I want 0 to be in that cell and if not it should put the answer to the calculation.

eg. =If(cell1<0,0,cell1)

I want this in the same cell and not in a separate cell

Comment: How about `=max(0,formula_here)`?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to repeat the formula within the `IF` statement.

```
=IF(SUM(I19)-Sum(K19/100*I19)<0,0,SUM(I19)-Sum(K19/100*I19))
```

It's clunky, but that's the best you can do in Excel without writing a custom function in VBA.